# web service authentication using php

Tags: php, xml, soap

```
POST /xxxx/service.asmx HTTP/1.1
Host: xxx.xxx.xxx.xx
Content-Type: text/xml; charset=utf-8
Content-Length: length
SOAPAction: "http://apps.org/GetLogin"

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
  <soap:Body>
    <GetLogin xmlns="http://nhiapps.org/">
      <username>string</username>
      <password>string</password>
      <AppsID>string</AppsID>
    </GetLogin>
  </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
  <soap:Body>
    <GetLoginResponse xmlns="http://nhiapps.org/">
      <GetLoginResult>string</GetLoginResult>
    </GetLoginResponse>
  </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

This is my SOAP code.
I want to perform web service authentication using PHP. I have to call the get login function present in the IP address for authentication completion.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest that you use an existing framework.

Just include http://framework.zend.com/manual/current/en/modules/zend.soap.client.html with composer and it should work.